# Why gammu only works with sudo?

Tags: sudo, ubuntu-18.04, rules, huawei-mobile-services, gammu

I use gammu on a Raspberry PI 3, running Ubuntu 18.04.3 and a Huawei E303C 3G modem (in "/dev/ttyUSB0").

The program seems to work fine, but I always need to invoke "sudo" to complete the commands. Otherwise the following message is displayed: "Error opening device, you do not have the required permission.".

In Google searches and right here in Stackoverflow describri that you need to grant permissions on the device. I tried two different settings but none affected gammu behavior, it still requires sudo in all operations.

First I created the file "/etc/udev/rules.d/69-gammu-acl.rules" with the following content

```
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="gammu_acl_rules_end"

KERNEL!="ttyUSB[0-9]*", GOTO="gammu_acl_rules_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="tty", GOTO="gammu_acl_rules_end"

ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1506", TAG+="uaccess"

LABEL="gammu_acl_rules_end"
```

Then I created the file "/etc/udev/rules.d/99-phone.rules" with the following content:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1506", NAME="phone", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="phone"
```

The way is this really ?! Is something wrong with my settings ?! Could you help me?!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

First of all you should know what users you have, you can know with this command

```
  $ whoami
user_name
```

You must enter the name of the user in this command:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G dialout user_name
```

You must restart the computer to be added to the new group.

Then you can use gammu without the sudo command, for example:

```
$ gammu sendsms TEXT +589999999999 -text "Halooo .."
```

*This work for me.*